# How to handle null while parsing Json in scala

Tags: json, scala

I have one Json file in format like some time it comes as

```
"cancelled_date":null
```

and sometime it comes as

```
 "cancelled_date":{
            "$date":"2015-06-21T17:30:14.000Z"
  }
```

so to handle this I have written code like

```
var date = scala.util.Try(value.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]])
```

but when i am getting the value from the date map

```
date.get("date")
```

it is printing the whole map as it is like

```
Map($date -> 2015-04-28T19:48:37.000Z)
```

I am not able to understand why it is returning the whole map itself ,it should return only its value.

Comment: What are the value and date? Try to print out those.

Comment: @znurgi while printing "value"  i get the same as Map($date -> 2015-04-28T19:48:37.000Z) and date is also printing the same as i am taking this as a map Instance

Comment: How do you build the variable  `value` ? The `get` works as you expect: `Try(Map("a"->"b")).get("a")`  => `String = b` in the REPL. Note: I would not "unwrap" the `Try` and `Map` this way but rather something like: `date.getOrElse { Map[String,String]() }.get("date")`

Comment: @BrunoGrieder i know this fact even i has also tried this and it is working.I think some problem is coming when i convert the instance of "$date":"2015-06-21T17:30:14.000Z" to map  while wrapping up it in Try(I am  wrapping it with Try to avoid the case when it is coming as null)